# SQL: How to Select Rows Based on a Date in the Table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Full disclosure, this is for homework, but I haven't been able to figure it out after looking through the text and looking around online.

We have a table: EMP with employee numbers: EMPNO, employee names: ENAME, hiredates: HIREDATE, salaries: SAL, etc...

The question is asking "Create a query to display the name and hire date of any employee hired after employee Smith."

I can easily set up a query to pull all employees who were hired after 12-17-1980 (the date currently set as Smith's hiredate), but I'm trying to figure out how to set up a query that will pull data based on whatever value is in the HIREDATE column of SMITH's row so that if Smith's hire date is updated, the query will reflect the new hire date without any input from me.

I feel like there's some piece of the SQL puzzle I'm overlooking and I can't quite figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Hint: you can use a SELECT statement in the WHERE clause: `where hiredate > (select ....)`

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know if I missed that in the book or just forgot it, but that makes this so much more straightforward. I don't know if this is exactly what the instructor is looking for since this lab is all about different types of joins and self-joins and I assumed that's where I'd find the answer, but this accomplishes the ask. Thanks so much!

Comment: Self-join would also work - EMP (all employees) joined to EMP (Smith) and compare the hire dates.

Comment: @WesHampton - I'm glad you got your solution.  For future reference, please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: @Tony Andrews - I think that's what the instructor is looking for. I don't know why this didn't click for me to join them where s.ename = 'smith' and then compare the dates. I'm still getting a handle on how all of these operators affect the queries. Thanks for the follow up. This helps my understanding quite a bit and I was able to produce what I think is the actual code he's looking for.

Comment: While "still getting a handle on how all of these operators affect the queries" is common to everybody beginning with SQL at least you are trying and looking at set processing and not regressing to trying loops. *Good for you*.  It will take some time get that handle, but by trying you will. And it is time well spent - you will be much better because of it.